# fail to publish to a different message type

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone :)
I wrote a node called translater that subscribes to a the topic **pose_before** and publishes to another topic **pose_after**. The topic **pose_before** is of message type "PoseWithCovarianceStamped" and **pose_after** is "TransformStamped". The issue is that all values in **pose_after** remain 0 when they're being published.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseWithCovarianceStamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped

def callback(data):
    TransformStamped().transform.translation.x = data.pose.pose.position.x
    TransformStamped().transform.translation.y = data.pose.pose.position.y
    TransformStamped().transform.translation.z = data.pose.pose.position.z
    TransformStamped().transform.rotation.x = data.pose.pose.orientation.x
    TransformStamped().transform.rotation.y = data.pose.pose.orientation.y
    TransformStamped().transform.rotation.z = data.pose.pose.orientation.z
    TransformStamped().transform.rotation.w = data.pose.pose.orientation.w
def listener():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('pose_after', TransformStamped, queue_size=40)
    pose_after = TransformStamped()
    rospy.init_node('translater', anonymous=True)
    rospy.loginfo("Publishing pose_after")
    rospy.Subscriber('pose_before', PoseWithCovarianceStamped, callback)
    rate = rospy.Rate(40)
    pose_after.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    pose_after.child_frame_id = 'base_footprint'
    print(pose_after.transform.translation.x) # this prints (0,0)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pub.publish(pose_after)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        listener()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

When I put the print line in callback then it actually is able to print the correct values, so I'm wondering why the values are lost outside of the callback. I've also tried assigning a global variable inside the callback but still didn't work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368669/fail-to-publish-to-a-different-message-type/) by [Patricia2602](https://answers.ros.org/users/61733/patricia2602/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should really be using classes. But here is a hack that works

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseWithCovarianceStamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped

pub = rospy.Publisher('pose_after', TransformStamped, queue_size=40)
pose_after = TransformStamped()

def callback(data):

    pose_after.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    pose_after.child_frame_id = 'base_footprint'

    pose_after.transform.translation.x = data.pose.pose.position.x
    pose_after.transform.translation.y = data.pose.pose.position.y
    pose_after.transform.translation.z = data.pose.pose.position.z
    pose_after.transform.rotation.x = data.pose.pose.orientation.x
    pose_after.transform.rotation.y = data.pose.pose.orientation.y
    pose_after.transform.rotation.z = data.pose.pose.orientation.z
    pose_after.transform.rotation.w = data.pose.pose.orientation.w

    print(pose_after.transform) # this prints (0,0)
    pub.publish(pose_after)

def listener():
    
    rospy.init_node('translater', anonymous=True)
    rospy.loginfo("Publishing pose_after")

    rospy.Subscriber('pose_before', PoseWithCovarianceStamped, callback)
    rate = rospy.Rate(40)
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        listener()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

In your original callback, you are trying to populate TransformStamped() which is a msg type, not a msg. you should be able to echo the pose_after topic and listen in on the new msgs now.

---

Originally posted by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) with karma: 459 on 2020-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patricia2602](https://answers.ros.org/users/61733/patricia2602/) on 2020-12-30**:
Thanks for the reply :) I realized that the print() just always give me (0,0) when I put it outside of the callback, but when I echo the rostopic the values are no longer 0 anymore, which also makes sense if we do everything in the callback. Not sure if it was also the case for my previous versions, where I was populating pose_after but then decided to try TransformStamped(), which was obviously wrong.